# Can I trigger Team City build from Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, command-line, teamcity, command-prompt

I have setup a Teamcity Project in Windows system within Teamcity. 
But I wish to trigger the Teamcity build from Windows command prompt.
Is this possible?
If yes, Is there any documentation or setup guide for this?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the TeamCity documentation:

```
curl -v -u user:password http://teamcity.server.url:8111/app/rest/buildQueue --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @build.xml
```

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild

Comment: Thanks for resonse! I was wondering where do I need to store my build.xml having the build id and agent id?

Comment: Try using the build config xml from the page:"<build <buildType id="buildConfID"/></build>"